# MySQL Location Query Not Comparing Against Actual Location?

Tags: php, android, mysql, geolocation, localhost

So I am trying to create a complex mysql query to help sort out my location data stored in my database.

I've got four fields: id, latitude, longitude, timestamp.

What I want to do is compare my database entries against the current location of the device. Not setting a prefixed lat and long and comparing against that.

I've experimented with the Haversine Forumula which is used for distance, but its not exactly what I need. Any Ideas?

The query I need has: Needs to show me the the closest location minimum (~50m) from my actual cellphone location through indexing the existing locations stored in my database. Any ideas?

My query currently: (My Haversine Experimentation)

```
set @orig_lat=32.42; 
set @orig_long=-221.50; 
set @bounding_distance=1;

SELECT * ,((ACOS(SIN(@orig_lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(`latitude` * PI() /
    180) + COS(@orig_lat * PI() / 180) * COS(`latitude` * PI() / 180) *
    COS((@orig_long - `longitude`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 *
    1.1515) AS `distance`
FROM `Location`
WHERE ( `latitude` BETWEEN
    (@orig_lat - @bounding_distance) AND (@orig_lat + @bounding_distance)
    AND `longitude` BETWEEN (@orig_long - @bounding_distance) AND
    (@orig_long + @bounding_distance) )
ORDER BY `distance` ASC limit 1
```

Comment: exactly how is this not working?

Comment: @Marc B...Well, it works but its not exactly what I need...I want to know how it goes against using and comparing using actual real location?

Comment: @MarcB Also, my bounding distance is set in degrees by 1, how can I get a query that does 50meters or greater?

Comment: One solution would be to just get all entries from the database, and put the logic to check if  within 50 meters in the Java code.

Comment: @DanielNugent...Could you please give me an explanation using code please? I am trying to get the the specific result running a query then displaying it in a textview...

Comment: Are you saying you want results greater than 50 meters and less than the bounding box of +/- 1 degree bounding box ?

Comment: @davidstrachan...I just want results up to 50 meters, and am not sure a bounding box is needed? Could you help clarify the definition. My understanding is based on mine (1) it covers an area of ~69miles  or 1 degree from my set location of lat/long. so all the queries within the 69miles shows up as results...correct?